# Disabling the form designer in DelphiXE

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe, form-designer

Is it possible to disable the form designer in DelphiXE "on-demand/selectively" and only work with the code of a form/class where needed, in the event that controls are not installed in the IDE?

Comment: @David, missed the "in the event that controls are not installed in the IDE" part of the question...

Comment: @David: AFAICT the OP wants to avoid the IDE deleting unknown components and properties if he edits non-component-related code. This shouldn't pose a problem for the code editor (including error insight and whatnot) as long as the components' code or DCUs are accessible.

Comment: You're fighting delphi here.  If you don't stop fighting it, you'll start hating it. It's better not to fight this one.  You could look into having multiple registry hives per project you work on, each one with the components you need installed, and then you would just have to launch the IDE you want with the -RBDS_OPTX parameter to go to the alternate BDS_OPTX registry area.

Comment: There are some components in use/under construction that change and this causes exceptions in the IDE as well, besides that, the fact of not wanting to be tethered to the form designer all the time and having oodles of components loaded into the Delphi (environment runtime as it uses memory and causes memory leaks). The standard Delphi IDE behaviour is OK for "dropping, arranging and event mapping" but a lot of code happens after that. Qt has found a good balance - so has MSVS with C# forms.

Comment: See my comments below on my answer. You're still doing it wrong, even in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the answer is no, but the workaround that I use is to edit the DFM file and cut out the component that is not there, and paste it to the FormCreate event and instantiate it there instead. The properties are all there in the DFM, so a little editing makes it work nicely.

Comment: That's fine if removing the component from the dfm doesn't destroy the layout of the whole rest of the form.    And it's easier said than done with a really complex control.  Component to code expert is great for a single component with 30 or less properties, but if it's a component with subcomponents and Lists of Properties, that need to be viewable and editable, you lose a lot of functionality this way.

Comment: @Warren If the component is that important, then you'd want to install it again. But for layout, I have in the past used a TPanel to show the position, and then used that as the parent. That way you can still design around it.

Comment: Mj2008: Agreed.  Panels are a good solution to that! I have pulled some components OUT of designtime when I felt that it was too much of a pain to keep it working. And there are sometimes issues where your app breaks because a designtime problem caused your OnImportantEvent handler to become disconnected, which causes no compiler messages and is a silent-but-deadly failure at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't disable it selectively. What I often do (as I have hardly any controls installed in most of my IDE's) is that I just open the form, tell Delphi to ignore all errors when loading the dfm, do my editing of the source code and make sure I don't check in the dfm to my source control system.

You could try to keep the dfm readonly to avoid mistakenly checking in a dfm with deleted controls, but there is a drawback to that: every time you try to save your source the IDE will come up with an error about the readonly-ness of the file. If you hit Ctrl-S or Shft-Ctrl-S as often as I do, that quickly becomes a nuisance.

When I do have to change the dfm, I do it in text mode, or install the controls, do the dfm changes and submit. After that I am free again to de-install the controls and just work on the pas file, ignoring / reverting any changes to the dfm.

Comment: What I usually do is select "Cancel" in the "Error Reading Form" dialog, then select "OK" to dismiss the following "Error creating form: ..." dialog. It's just two clicks or two presses of the Escape key. No form designer is created and I can still edit and save the .pas file without touching the .dfm.

Comment: @TOndrej: Aha, that sounds good. I'll try cancelling next time around.

Comment: The similar you can use in case you have for instance inconsistent event headers (this happened to me when migrating from the old VirtualTreeView component and there were different parameters in the events) and you need just to modify the source and save it. When you press the `Save` button you will get the message like `The parameters of the method XXX doesn't correspond to its declaration. Do you want to remove it ?`, if you select `Cancel` or press `ESC` then nothing is removed and your file is successfully saved.

Comment: @TOndrej: That helps a bit - never clicked that button for some reason

Answer (score 1):

No, and there is no reasonable workaround for it at this time.

I have asked for this to be a feature in Delphi at some point in the future; That DFMs should not be destroyed by opening them, nor should multiple modal dialog boxes asking if you want to destroy your DFMs be the default behaviour when opening a form that does not have the controls installed.

In the end there is only one practical solution; Install all the controls.  Anything else is just going to drive you crazy.

Comment: Who was behind the decision to show a gazillion dialogs all with an identical message?!!

Comment: I wouldn't assume anybody thought about it at all.  Essentially such problems don't affect your ability to demo a trivial Delphi RAD workflow, and such problems become crippling when Delphi apps reach a certain scale, and when you are a developer who works with component sets that are mutually exclusive, among multiple projects. Managing these component sets per project is a hell of a big Delphi problem.

Comment: Yeah, just like the program manager is probably never used with a projectgroup with 51 big and small projects in it... It regularly crashes on a build all sometimes even when you haven't done anything else yet. Or units with a lot of conditional defines, not only in the code but in the uses clause as well. It throws code insight in loops...

Comment: @David Heffernan: Adding injury to insult [sic] - in XE - the "Save changes?" OK button is located in the same position as the last dialogs' "Ignore" button - resulting in unintentional saves if you you just "click away" at them.

Comment: @WarrenP - installing them is not practical - pls see my comment on the question

Comment: If you have components in use and under construction YOU SHOULD BE USING MULTIPLE REGISTRY HIVES for stable, and unstable environments (run bds.exe -RBDS_ALT).  Then you won't have this problem.  Ask another question about setups for component development if you like. These component development scenarios have solutions and workflows that work better than not installing components.

Comment: @WarrenP: I tried bds.exe -RBDS_ALT and it does nothing - BDS does not start. The help system is not instructive on this - could you please help?

Comment: If bds does not start and no splash screen even comes up, were you running from the folder where BDS.exe is located, or was BDS.exe in your path?  Try running the fully qualified path: "C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0\bin\bds.exe -RBDS_ALT", from a shortcut.